# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR

Tags: php, json

I want to output like this

```
var data = { 
{
"cname": "Albania"
}
{
"cname": "Austria"
}
}
```

This code i tried but i am getting an error `"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in C:\wamp\www\mvc\map\data.php on line 22"`

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');  // this is the magic that sets responseJSON

 $dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Could not select database');

        $query = "SELECT cname FROM country";       // Performing SQL query
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        $all_recs = array();
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $all_recs[] = $line;
        }


var data = {

echo json_encode($all_recs);

};

// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

can anyone guide me how to fix this,thanks

Comment: Where did you read that kind of syntax ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want that, but you can mix js code in php like this, you may try

```
$jsonData = json_encode($all_recs);
echo "var data = {$jsonData}";
```

Comment: +1 for understanding what the OP wanted ... i was clueless, thought about some weird kind of array ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = "cname : Albania cname : Austria";
```